# How to dismiss keyboard when using DecimalPad

Tags: iphone, keyboard, xamarin.ios

I have a `UITableView` with a custom cell that has a `TextField`. I have the **DecimalPad** comes up, and as we all know, there is no done key. I previously had resolved this type of issue when I had a "Decimal only" textfield on a normal UIView by handling the `TouchesEnded` event and then checking to see if the `TextField` was the first responder and if so, it would then resign, but if that technique could work now then I'm not able to figure out who's `TouchesEnded` I should be using (The `UIView` that everything is presented on, the `UITableView`, the Cell, the CellControler, the TextField.. I think I've tried everything).

I'm hoping there's another, cleaner way of dealing with this.

Anyone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[I think David has the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533260/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-when-using-decimalpad/5533554#5533554) - here is some Monotouch code to get you started. You will need to put this in the View Controller where the decimal pad is being shown:

```
UIView dismiss;

public override UIView InputAccessoryView 
{
    get 
    {
        if (dismiss == null)
        {
            dismiss = new UIView(new RectangleF(0,0,320,27));
            dismiss.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(new UIImage("Images/accessoryBG.png"));          
            UIButton dismissBtn = new UIButton(new RectangleF(255, 2, 58, 23));
            dismissBtn.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage("Images/dismissKeyboard.png"), UIControlState.Normal);        
            dismissBtn.TouchDown += delegate {
                 textField.ResignFirstResponder();
            };
            dismiss.AddSubview(dismissBtn);
        }
        return dismiss;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks. Given that this is in a Custom Cell, on a UITAbleView, on a UIView, do I put this in the Cell Controller or the UIView?

Comment: That's a good question...I  think you'll want to place it in the Cell Controller

Comment: Actually I just put it on the 'root' UIView and it worked like a charm. AMAZING.

Answer (score 9):

If you're targeting iOS 4.0 or greater you can create an [inputAccessoryView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIResponder/inputAccessoryView) containing a Done button to attach to the keyboard that will dismiss the keyboard when tapped.  [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) is an example from the documentation on creating a simple inputAccessoryView.

Answer (score 3):

You could dismiss it when the user taps on the background; I think that's the most intuitive way.

In Interface Builder, change your View's class to `UIControl`. This is a subclass of `UIView`, so your program will work the same way, but you also get the standard touch events.

From here it's simple, create a method for the *Touch Down* event:
`[numberField resignFirstResponder]`

Of course it might be slightly different with MonoTouch -- unfortunately I don't know much about it, but wanted to help.
Hopefully you can use the concept, and modify your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Or you may just add some gesture to your main view.
For example:

```
//Just initialise the gesture you want with action that dismisses your num pad
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{    
     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeToHideNumPad = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideNumPad:)];
            swipeToHideNumPad.delegate = self;
            swipeToHideNumPad.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
            [swipeToHideNumPad setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

            [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeToHideNumPad];
}


//action
- (void)hideNumPad:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    [self.amountTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```